# ssh tmux: execute long running command using ssh programmatically

Tags: ssh, tmux

I need to programmatically execute long running script on a remote server. I tried to use ssh with screen or tmux and so far I could not make it work.

With tmux I managed to make it work when typing the ssh command from my local machine terminal:

```
ssh <server_name> -t -t tmux new -s my_session \; set-buffer "bash my_script.sh" \; paste-buffer \; send-keys C-m \; detach
```

But if I run this programmatically I get this error:

```
open terminal failed: missing or unsuitable terminal: unknown
Connection to <server_name> closed
```

Comment: "if I run this programatically..." Please [edit] your question to include the code that you're using to invoke the command.

Answer (score 3):

Use the -d flag to new-session to start tmux detached. So:

```
ssh <server_name> tmux new -ds my_session \; send-keys "bash my_script.sh" C-m
```

Comment: It seems to be working. Thank you!